# OpenCV more efficent background subtraction solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, background-subtraction

There is a scenario that I have to identify round/oval marks that are placed on the tiled floor. I tried to use the following background subtraction algorithms that are inbuild with OpenCV separately.

```
filter1 = cv.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
filter2 = cv.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
filter3 = cv.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorGMG()
```

The result came as following respectively (the first image is the original image and rest are resultant images)

[image]

As you can see the black circle that I want to identify is not identified. So I used following thresholding command to identify the mark.

```
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(img, 75, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

Which gives the following result.

[image]

It identifies the mark but I am not sure the thresholding method will work efficiency in different lighting and background.

So what I seek is a better solution, that I can identify the mark more accurately.

Comment: Not python, but you can try to bind. https://github.com/Smorodov/ellipseDetector
it is my port of MATLAB ellipse detector from here: https://github.com/AlanLuSun/High-quality-ellipse-detection it not realtime (0.3 sec per frame, bur works rather robust.

Comment: the general background subtraction methods assume that you have a mostly static scene with changing foreground, like a static camera with a static scene and a dynamic object. You are looking dor foreground extraction. Try Otsu Thresholding

Comment: Please always post separate original images without the scales. Use cv2.imwrite rather than Mathplotpy. That way other uses can demonstrate solutions.

Comment: @Micka I was completed as you suggest and with your guide, I understand the issue is I am trying to use a method that is suitable for the video to the static image. could you post the idea in your comment as an answer. So, I could mark it as a correct answer.